# Angular filter causing infidig error

Tags: angularjs

I have the following angular filter being used into an ng-repeat that's causing a infidig error, and I can't understand how to fix it:

```
app.filter('orderByTime', function() {
  return function(items) {
    return items.sort(function(a, b) {
      a = moment(a.departure.time, "HH:mm");
      b = moment(b.departure.time, "HH:mm");

      if (a.isAfter(b)) {
        return 1;
      }
      if (a.isBefore(b)) {
        return -1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
  };
});
```

`moment` is from the library moment.js. The intent of this filter is to order a list of flight by the time of departure.

After a bit of discussion in the comments, the problem is caused by how I'm assigning the value to the variable:

```
$scope.flightList = []

var url = '/api/schedule/' + $rootScope.depAriportIATA;
if ($rootScope.desAriportIATA) {
   url += '/' + $rootScope.desAriportIATA;
}
$http.get(url).success(function(flights) {
   $scope.flightList = flights;
});
```

Comment: can you provide demo

Comment: @farhatmihalko working on it

Comment: How is the filter being used? Are you using it in a `ng-repeat` by any chance?

Comment: @ivarni yes, exactly

Comment: Then I *suspect* the problem is that you're reassigning `a` and `b`. What happens if you use some temporary variables instead of changing the reference?

Comment: @ivarni In my not-replicable real world scenario, I'm using an AJAX $http request to assign the values. But if I manually assign the value to the $scope, it works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @ivarni relevant code added to the question

Comment: I was talking about the `a = moment(a.departure.time, "HH:mm");` part. It's very possible that reassigning the `a` reference over and over again keeps triggering `ng-repeat` to re-evaluate its list.

Comment: @ivarni well, if I need to, angular have to compare the previous element in the array with the next one. But Isn't it interesting that if I directly assign the values to the scope, the error is not fired?